# how to autoload webpage when there any value are added

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

i am working on a Group Chat Application project using node,express  and in front end i am using ajax.
so when any user add or message add then how can i automatic load the web page and simultaneously show the newly added data in the web page. 
i am currently using this:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

but this only occurred in the same browser same page, not in other browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CHAT APP</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- jquery emoji picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.emojipicker.css">

    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Emoji Data -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.emojipicker.tw.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->

    <style>
      body {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        background: url('https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/74401/screenshots/1645509/astronaut.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
      }

      .chat-section {
        display: none;
      }

      #noMsgErr {
        display: none;
      }

      h1, h2 {
        color: darkgray;
      }

    </style>
  </head>



  <body>

    <!-- User Registration Form. To be displayed only for the first time. -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="userRegistration">
        <h2>Register Yourself First!</h2>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-11">
            <div class="well">
              <label>Enter UserName: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter user name" id="registeredUser"
                    onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) { $('#regUserSubmitBtn').click();}"/>
                <br>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-success" id="regUserSubmitBtn"> SUBMIT </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      
      <div class="chat-section">
        <h1 class="text-center">Let's Chat!</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-0"  id='onlineUsersSection'>
              <div class="well">
                <label>Online Users:</label><br>
                <ul id="users"></ul>
              </div>
            </div>

          <div class="col-md-8 chatDiv">
            <div id="chats"></div>

            <div class="well" id="typeMsgSection">
              <label for="Chats" class='peopleTyping'>Type Message: </label>

              <br/>
              <input type="text" placeholder="enter message" id="sentMessage" class="form-control"
                      onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) {$('#hitSend').click();}"></input>
              <br/>

              <div class="alert alert-danger" id="noMsgErr">
                <p>Blank Messsages are not entertained</p>
              </div>

              <br/>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="hitSend">Send</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <button class="btn btn-warning" id="clearChat">Clear Chat</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </body>

  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
      
      var domHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
      var hasMsg = false;       // to check whether there is some value in the input message field, so that once there is a value in the input message field, we need not check again on "keyup". We only need to check once there is no value in the input message field.

      console.log('domHeight', domHeight);
      var flag = true;

      /* SECTION - DOM Caching */
      $userRegistration = $('#userRegistration');
      $registeredUser = $('#registeredUser');
      $users = $('#users');
      $chats = $('#chats');
      $sentMessage = $('#sentMessage');
      $hitSend = $('#hitSend');
      $clearChat = $('#clearChat');
      $regUserSubmitBtn = $('#regUserSubmitBtn');
      $typeMsgSection = $('#typeMsgSection');

      $registeredUser.focus();      // giving the user name input field the cursor.

      var socketClient = io();
      socketClient.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connected on client - ', socketClient.id);
        if($chats.html() == 0) {
          $clearChat.attr('disabled', true);
        }
        $hitSend.attr('disabled', true);
      });

      /* SECTION - User typing the message */
      $sentMessage.on('keyup', function() {
        if($(this).val()) {
          //$("#noMsgErr").hide();
          $hitSend.attr('disabled', false);
          
          if(!hasMsg) {
            hasMsg = true;      // if there is some value in the input message field, we need not check again.
            socketClient.emit('addTypingUsers');
          }

        } else {
          $hitSend.attr('disabled', true);
          hasMsg = false; // if there is some value in the input message field, we might check again until there is some value.

          // if there is no value in the input message field, remove the current user from "Typing users" list.
          socketClient.emit('removeTypingUsers');
        }
      });

      /* SECTION - Sending a new Message */
      $hitSend.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let msg = $sentMessage.val();

        if(msg == '') {
          //$("#noMsgErr").show();
          return;
        }

        $sentMessage.val('');
        socketClient.emit("oldMessage", {msg: msg});
        hasMsg = false;

        // once the message is sent, remove the name of the user from "Typing users" list.
        socketClient.emit('removeTypingUsers');
        $('.peopleTyping').text('Type Message:  ');
      });


      /* SECTION - Clear Chat */
      $clearChat.on('click', function() {
        $clearChat.attr('disabled', true);  // disabling the clear chats button.
        $sentMessage.focus();   // setting cursor on input field.

        flag = true;
        domHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;

        // remove scroll bar, height, padding slowly from the chats section.
        $chats.animate({
          'height': '0px',
          'overflow-y': 'hidden',
          'padding-right': '0px'
        }, 'slow', function() {
          $chats.removeAttr('style');
          $chats.empty();
        });

        $typeMsgSection.css({
          'margin-top': '0px'
        });

        $('.peopleTyping').text('Type Message:  ');
      });


      /* SECTION - User Registration */
      $regUserSubmitBtn.on('click', function() {
        var currentUser = $registeredUser.val();
        if(currentUser == '') {
          alert('please enter a name');
          return;
        }

        socketClient.emit("thisUser", {user: currentUser, onlineStatus: 'green'});

        $registeredUser.val('');

        $userRegistration.fadeOut("slow", function() {
          // remove the user registration section and show chats section on the page
          $(".chat-section").fadeIn("slow");

          // activating the jquery emoji picker
          $sentMessage.emojiPicker({
            position: 'right'
          });

          var $emojiPickerDiv = $('#typeMsgSection > div')[0];
          $emojiPickerDiv.style.width = '100%';

          // taking care of the UI gliches that come when jquery-emoji-picker is installed
          // makes the 'text' input take the width of the div it is enclosed in
          $sentMessage[0].style.width = '100%';
          // makes the 'text' input responsive
          $sentMessage[0].style.display = 'flex';

          // to put the cursor on "#sentMessage" input text field
          $sentMessage.focus();
        });
      });
      

      /* SECTION - Appending new message */
      socketClient.on('newMessage', function(data) {
        let prevOffsetTop = 0, currOffsetTop = 0;

        if($chats.html() == '') {
          prevOffsetTop = $typeMsgSection.offset.top;
        }

        $chats.append('<div class="well well-sm" style="font-size: 18px">' + '<strong>'+ data.user + ': </strong>' + data.msg + '</div>').fadeIn('slow');
        
        $chats.scrollTop($chats[0].scrollHeight);

        if($chats.contents().length == 1) {
          currOffsetTop = $typeMsgSection.offset.top;
        }

        $typeMsgSection.css({
          'margin-top': '15px'
        });

        // when the user sends a message, the "chats" section must become fixed at the end of the page. Hence, we scrolled the window down. (params : (x, y) // x = document.boyd.scrollwidth, y = document.body.scrollHeight)

        //window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        //console.log('domHeight', domHeight);
        if(flag && ($typeMsgSection.offset().top + $typeMsgSection.height() + parseInt($typeMsgSection.css('margin-top')) 
                      + parseInt($('body').css('margin-top')) + currOffsetTop - prevOffsetTop >= domHeight)) {
          $chats.css({
            'overflow-y': 'scroll',       // giving the chats section a scroll bar.
            'padding-right': '10px',      // padding at the side of scroll bar.
            'height': $typeMsgSection.position().top - parseInt($('body').css('margin-top')) - parseInt($typeMsgSection.css('margin-top'))
          });

          $chats.scrollTop($chats[0].scrollHeight);
          flag = false;
        }
        
        $clearChat.attr('disabled', false);
      })


      /* SECTION - user Online/Away - making the current user "Away" once the fouce on the browser tab is shifted*/
      $(window).blur(function() {
        // sending the server an event that will change the current users status to "Away" on server level.
        socketClient.emit("updateUserStatus", 'yellow');
        return;
      });

      /* SECTION - user Online/Away - making the current user "Online" once the focus on the browser tab is back. */
      $(window).focus(function() {
        // sending the server an event that will change the current users status to "Away" on server level.
        socketClient.emit("updateUserStatus", 'green');
        return;
      });


      /* SECTION - showing online users */
      socketClient.on('all-Users', function(obj) {
        let html = '';
        let imgSrc = '';   // variable to store the source of either "Yellow dot" or "Green dot" (for Online/Away symbol).

        for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
          if(obj[i].status == 'green') {
            imgSrc = ' <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Online_dot.png" alt="online-green-dot" height="8px" width="8px"/> ';
          } else {
            imgSrc = ' <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6f/Yellow_Dot_by_DraGoth.png/600px-Yellow_Dot_by_DraGoth.png" alt="online-green-dot" height="8px" width="8px"/> ';
          }

          html +=  '<li class="list-group-item"> ' + imgSrc + obj[i].user + '</li>';
        }

        $users.empty();
        $users.append(html);
      });

      /* SECTION - showing typing users */
      socketClient.on('showTypingUsers', function(data) {
        let str = '';    // will store the names of users currently typing. (If their no. is less than 3)

        var cnt = 0;   // variable that stores the number of people currently typing other than the current user.

        data.forEach(function(obj) {
          if(obj.uId != socketClient.id) {
            str += obj.uName + ', ';
            cnt++;
          }
        });

        str = str.substring(0, str.length - 2);

        if(cnt == 0) {
          $('.peopleTyping').text('Type Message: ');
        }
        else if(cnt == 1) {
          $('.peopleTyping').text('Type Message:  ' + str + ' is typing...');
        }
        else if(cnt == 2){
          $('.peopleTyping').text('Type Message:  ' + str + ' are typing...');
        }
        else {
          $('.peopleTyping').text('Type Message:  ' + cnt + ' people are typing...');
        }
        
      });

    });

</script>

<!-- jquery emoji picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.emojipicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.emojis.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem *!?*

Comment: jst autoload the page when any one visit the page and also autoload the page when a user make any botton click event.